# How to make a film dynamic url link

Tags: java, php, html, video, html5-video

I see some movie share station they film link is dynamic 
like : the first time I get it is 
http://a309.static-file.com:8080/video/552140e4f31ff2e66b97ea3801364238/59cb66ec/mp4/v2/170927/df8655e484f3b2174e66b31bbeea438a.mp4

but the second time I get it's 
http://a309.static-file.com:8080/video/c116b15012858c9cf67bde64b0b6a863/59cb6700/mp4/v2/170927/df8655e484f3b2174e66b31bbeea438a.mp4

have any software can do it ? 
because I google can't find about it 
but I thought there was a way when everytime guest get film 
check the link is or not over 24h ,if over 24h ,then change the film name
but I think that is not good efficient idea

Answer (score 0):

There can be n number of ways to do it. One simplest way is to create an internal mapping of "resource" for a particular session.

eg file at server is movie1.mp4. Two logged in users are supposed to see the same file.

Traditionally you can link http://server.com/movie1.mp4. Or what you can do is for user1, session1, you can create a hash with some key xyz123 that will map to movie1.mp4.

Now assume your resourceservlet got called for http://server.com/moviewfinder/somehashkey... you go, figure the value of this hashkey, figure the session etc and then serve the mapped movie1.